# Is Java Cross-IDE plugin development possible?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, intellij-plugin, netbeans-plugins

This is a simple yes or no answer out of curiosity.

I've seen some pretty decent cross-platform java tools such as [Codemane One](http://www.codenameone.com/) (capable of generating applications for multiple mobile platforms  out of a sigle Java codebase). They handle major API differences and are able to generate cross-platform UI layers.

I am wondering if anyone is trying to accomplish the same thing for IDE plugin development? IDEs underlying platforms and development models are so complex that, even when they are written in the same language (such as Java), you end up developing separate plugins for each IDE.

So, is there a equivalent of *Codename One* targeting IDE plugin development? Is anyone working on that? (Obscure academic research is ok if they have developed something useful).

Comment: It is quite straightforward to create cross platform applications with Eclipse (such as Eclipse itself). I have several.

Comment: Gre, I don't mean simple cross-platform Swing / Java Fx / SWT / Console application, I mean plugins that can run in multiple IDES (you write it once and can install it in Eclipse, Intellij, Netbeans, etc).

Comment: I doubt it. The UI part of plugins maybe, but the  actual functionality depends too much on the API of the IDE and automagic tools are not smart enough to write intelligent code.

Comment: Given the disparate nature of IDE's I doubt this approach would ever work in practise. Best you can do is reuse the "core" of your plugin in each IDE.

Comment: @vikingsteve, I would say the same about mobile development (even worse, since they are running different APIs over different languages). In practice IDE have their underlying platform, UI layer, module system (lately all of the three mentioned are OSGi compatible), etc. I'm not saying that this is a easy problem to tackle, I'm just saying that if solutions for mobile are appearing, an abstraction to generate code for multiple IDEs should also be feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Java Specification Request 198](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=198) "A Standard Extension API for Integrated Development Environments" was released in 2006. However, nothing major seems to have happened from then. So, basically the answer is no.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't heard about it :). Googling a bit I've found a lot of references about JDeveloper trying to implement the API as well as discussions about when / if major IDES would join the bandwagon. Too bad it haven't gained enough momentum.

Comment: The spec lead & submitting member came from Oracle, the JDeveloper maker. Note that the Eclipse Foundation was not supporting this JSR.